# Uniform convergence of the reciprocals

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

If $f_n(x)$ converge to $f(x)$ uniformly on a domain E and if $f_n$ $f$ never vanish on E ($f_n(x)\neq0$ and $f(x)\neq0$) $\forall x\in E$ and n in natural numbers

then does it follow that the functions $1/f_n$ converge uniformly to $1/f$ on E?

I am not sure how to do this one.

Comment: Possible idea (maybe a long shot, I haven't checked the details): If you consider $E=(0,1)$ and $f_n(x) = x+\frac{1}{n}$, $f(x) = x$, what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need some stronger bounded-above-zero conditions.

Take $f_n(x) = 1/x + 1/n$ over $E = (0,\infty)$ and $f(x) = 1/x$. Note that
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 1/n < \varepsilon$$
for any $\varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, so we have uniform convergence. Now,
$$\left| \frac{1}{f_n(x)} - \frac{1}{f(x)} \right| = \left| \frac{xn}{n+x} - x\right| = \frac{x^2}{n+x}.$$
For fixed $n$, the supremum of the last quantity over $E$ is $+\infty$, so we do not have uniform convergence. We do have pointwise convergence, however!

Comment: hmm so to have uniform convegence the supremum would have to go to zero as n goes to infinity right?

Comment: Precisely. Uniform convergence is equivalent to the following statement: Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in E$. Put $M_n = \sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x) - f(x)|$. Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$ if and only if $M_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. If you stare at the statement long enough, you'll see that it is only a reformulation of the definition of uniform convergence. By requiring the sup of the error to go to 0, you are insisting that the overall error tend to 0 as well (since overall $\leq$ sup). Conversely, if the overall error is going to 0, certainly the supremum is too.

Comment: I see so this above example is a counter example which shows that the proposition is not true based on the given conditions.

Comment: Correct. But maybe if we insist $f_n(x) \geq M > 0$ for some $M$ for all $x$, the conclusion may hold.